# How to mock Instance DAO methods using PowerMock+EasyMock+Junit+Java

Tags: java, junit, dao, powermock, easymock

I am new to Unit Testing, got some requirement to mock DAO layer but not getting how to do it.
Below is my sample DAO code which is doing some transactional activities.

```
 Class DAOList{
 public Object getRows(Map mapObj, Object error) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from some_table ").addEntity(SomeObject.class);
        Object getObj = query.uniqueResult();
        return getObj;
    }

    catch (HibernateException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception occurred: " + exc.getMessage());
    }

    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
}   }
```

I tried writing test case like below but I am getting Runtime exception

```
    @TestSubject 
    Session sessionn;

    @Mock 
    Transaction transaction;

    @MockSession 
    session;

    @MockSQLQuery
    mockQuery;

    @Test
public void testSomeSuccessCheck() throws Exception {
    HashMap map = new HashMap();

    EasyMock.expect(HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession()).andReturn(sessionn);
    EasyMock.expect(session.beginTransaction()).andReturn(transactionn);
    EasyMock.expect(session.createSQLQuery(EasyMock.anyString()).addEntity(VehicleDetails.class)).andReturn(query);
    EasyMock.expect((SomeObject) query.uniqueResult()).andReturn(someObj);

    SomeObject respObj = vehDao.someMethod(map, errs);
    assertNotNull(respObj);
}
```

Complete Error Trace which I got:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@5c87bfe2 failed.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Have you forgotten to instantiate connection?
at org.easymock.internal.Injector.injectMocks(Injector.java:81)
at org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(EasyMockSupport.java:528)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1846)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:810)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:790)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:73)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
```

Comment: have you tried google? i don't mean to come across rude. but. there's tons of hits out there with your name all over them.

Comment: I have tried it and getting Runtime exception.I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to mock the static method call **HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory()** and then mock the **openSession**() method call. Rest will remaining as what you have added.

Refer this for more information on how to use PowerMock : https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/03/junit-testing-using-mockito-powermock/

You can also use Mockito + Powermock to solve the same problem.